# renderUI conditioned by a reactive value

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard

Today I am trying to have a renderUI for which the form and the content depend on the value of a reactiveValues. I am working on a shinydashBoard

At initial state, users will click on the button and the form of the renderUI will change. If users click one more time I would like that the renderUI takes the initial form again.

Here is my code :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

)

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("Text2Bis")


)#dashboardBody

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = list(icon("star-half-o"),"element-R")
  #messages,
  #notifications,
  #tasks
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  previewAction <- reactiveValues(temp = F)

  output$Text2Bis <- renderUI({

    if(is.null(input$button)){
      box(width = 12,background = NULL, height = 100,
          actionButton("button","delete")
      )
    }
    else{
      print(input$button)
      if((isolate(input$button %%2)) == 1){
        print(input$button)
        box(width = 12,background = NULL, height = 100,
            actionButton("button","delete")
        )

      }
      else{
        print(input$button)
        box(width = 12,background = NULL, height = 300,
            actionButton("button","save")
        )
      }

    }



  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can't understand why my app is not working. It seems that the actionButton is still reinitialized ???

Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thank you very much in advance !

Cheers

Cha

Comment: So it looks like the problem here is that your reactive that is creating the action button is actually checking the state of input$button, so every time that state changes, the whole thing gets run again. try isolating the sections with input$button

Comment: Basically, it doesn't matter if you isolate it in one place if you're printing the state of it elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I did it !!! So much work for this simple script !!

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

)

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("Text2Bis")


)#dashboardBody

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = list(icon("star-half-o"),"element-R")
  #messages,
  #notifications,
  #tasks
)

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  previewAction <- reactiveValues(temp = 1)

  output$Text2Bis <- renderUI({

    if((previewAction$temp%%2) ==1 ){
      box(width = 12,background = NULL, height = 100,
          actionButton("save","save")

      )
    }
    else{

      box(width = 12,background = NULL, height = 200,
          actionButton("hide","hide"),
          h4("YEAH !!")

      )

    }


  })




observe({
  if(input$save >0){
    isolate(previewAction$temp <- previewAction$temp+1)
  }
})

observe({
  if(input$hide >0){
    isolate(previewAction$temp <- previewAction$temp+1)
  }
})



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks a lot all of you for your help !!

Cheers